# oAuth 2 implementation in react js

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, servicenow

I need a little guidance. I am trying to implement oAuth2 authentication in my React JS application. Backend is in service now. In react on login button click, service now popup will open to authenticate user and will provide access token at redirect uri.

I am having client id, client secret, access token uri, authorization uri, redirect uri.

But couldn't find any specific library for react js that gives oauth2 implementation. Please give me pointers so I can use any existing/implement oauth2 authentication for my Login page(using react).

I was trying to use [ClientOAuth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-oauth2), but I am not sure if this is correct to use with react js. Also, I am getting CORS error on using this library on my localhost.

Please share how to implement it properly.

Answer (score 4):

I have a couple of tutorials you may find useful, which use the [oidc-client library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js).

The design patterns used are technology neutral and can be implemented in any JavaScript tech stack.

**TUTORIAL 1 : PLAIN TYPESCRIPT**

This focuses on the basics of Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) and a productive developer setup:

- [Blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)
- [Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1)

**FINAL TUTORIAL: REACTJS**

This focuses on some more advanced aspects, and includes an update to ReactJS:

- [Blog post](https://authguidance.com/2019/04/07/local-ui-setup/)
- [Code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final)

Answer (score 0):

I have used react-oauth2-auth-code-flow npm package to implement AUth2 flow in my react js application. The npm package has samples to help your implementation. Check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: This package has been deprecated.

Comment: yes, now i use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-oidc-context